# Is it possible to obtain a templateRef from a string?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ng-bootstrap

I am interested how you can obtain a `TemplateRef` by passing a `string` for example.

I don't want to obtain it through a component html, as I just want to save it in a config to be used for all components. I am refering to the ng-bootstrap `NgbDatePickerConfig` that can be viewed here: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker-config.ts.

Comment: I think you would need something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I was looking at that but I was hoping that there would be a shortcut to compiling a templateRef.

Comment: Not one I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3):

As Günter Zöchbauer pointed out, this is not possible and it probably is not too useful as you frequently would want to capture functionality for the `template` so you will need a Component for that.

However, currently it is not easy to create an isolated component that you just use to get a `TemplateRef`, as you need a `ViewContainerRef` in order to do that. 
Current Angular 2 issue that is targeting that: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9293.